# Trying to Make a Virtualenv on Windows 8 for Python but 'pip' is Not Recognized

Tags: python, windows, path, pip, virtualenv

I am new to programming and am trying to install `virtualenv` to set up my Python packages properly in one. I can see `Python39\scripts` is in my path, but cmd still says `pip is not recognized`.

As far as I can see I do not have any copies of Python installed, and have only moved the main file from `appdata` into a document folder titled Programming Languages for convenience. Any help or tips on this subject would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to recongiure the PATH because you moved it from appdata, and when you type pip it is looking for Python39\scripts in appdata. You have to paste the full new path in PATH in order for it to work.